# Create dataset id programmatically in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to create a Dataset programmatically in Bigquery? I am testing out a few things and need to create a few datasets on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's possible with the API

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/insert

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery now supports CREATE/ALTER/DROP SCHEMA statements. Please check the documentations:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_schema_statement

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_schema_set_options_statement

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#drop_schema_statement